# JOIN 3 QUERIES as a single table/view

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

How can I JOIN these 3 queries in to a single view

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM TABLE1

SELECT D,E,F FROM TABLE 2 WHERE G = 'TOM'

SELECT H,I,J FROM TABLE 2 WHERE G = 'HARRY'
```

```
OUTPUT TABLE/VIEW:

A,B,C,D,E,F,H,I,J
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```
SELECT A,B,C from T1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT D,E,F FROM T2 WHERE G ='TOM') ON T1.A = T2.D
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT H,I,J FROM T2 WHERE G = 'HARRY') as T3 ON T1.A = T3.H
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cross join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT A,B,C FROM TABLE1) t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT D,E,F FROM TABLE 2 WHERE G = 'TOM') tom CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT H,I,J FROM TABLE 2 WHERE G = 'HARRY') harry
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I am getting multiple rows as the output and I am expecting only 1 row

Comment: @Sin . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If this is generating multiple rows, that is because the subqueries return multiple rows -- and you need to figure out how to limit them to one row.  It is not part of your question.